# CocoaPods doesn't work after upgrading Mac OS X EI Capitain

Tags: cocoapods

I have this error when I am trying to install a pod using the Xcode plugin -- *CocoaPods* :
 "*The command path could not be resolved. Resolved command path for "pod" is invalid. Expanded GEM_PATH: /usr/bin.*"

After successfully reinstalling CocoaPods through Terminal and running command

`$ pod install`

I have this error:

`-bash: pod: command not found`

CocoaPods works fine before upgrading Mac OS

Answer (score 5):

Open terminal and:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
sudo chmod +rx /usr/local/bin/
```

Answer (score 0):

reinstall cocoapods with the command

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Comment: I tried.`cocoapods's executable "pod" conflicts with /usr/local/bin/pod
Overwrite the executable? [yN]` I chose y, and then installed succeeded. But any pod command still doesn't work.

Comment: @LiuDing you may need to open a new terminal window after installing.

Answer (score 0):

change path to /usr/local/bin : Xcode->product->cocoapods->GEM_PATH[picture shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6vsH.png)